# Laravel Foreach Controller vs View

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I realized something I can't figure out by myself.

I get a different result when I loop through first in a Controller and pass then the result to my view. Versus loop straight in my view.

For instance:
I have this in my Controller:

```
  public function index()
{
    $subscribers = Subscriber::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->orderBy('created_at','asc')->get();

    foreach ($subscribers as $key => $subscriber) {
      $var = $subscriber->name;
    }

    return view('backend.newsletter.contacts.index')->withSubscribers($subscribers)
                                                    ->withVar($var);
}
```

by using {{$var}} in my view I get only "John" as a result.

But when I use the foreach loop in my view instead of in the Controller:

```
@foreach($subscribers as $key => $subscriber)
 {{$subscriber->name}}
@endforeach
```

I get two results, "John" and "Dan". This makes totaly sense as I have two entries in my DB.

So how does it come that I get two different results here ?

Answer (score 5):

When you're doing this:

```
foreach ($subscribers as $key => $subscriber) {
    $var = $subscriber->name;
}
```

With each iteration you overwrite `$var` so you always get the last value. For example, if you have `['Dan', 'John, 'Alice', 'Alan']`, you'll get `Alan`.

Good practice is too pass data to a view and iterate it with `@foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

Because only the last loop iteration is stored in `$var`.

You need to

```
$var = [];
foreach ($subscribers as $key => $subscriber) {
     $var[] = $subscriber->name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding $var in the loop.

Try this:

`$var = [];
 foreach ($subscribers as $key => $subscriber) {
   $var[] = $subscriber->name; // Appends name to array
 }`